# Add menu bar above the WordPress administration bar

Tags: wordpress

I wish to add our own service menu above the WordPress administration bar in the administration area. I do not wish to hack the WordPress system, but I cannot find a hook.

Is there a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add extra menu items in your administrator menu bar instead of removing/replacing the menu bar.

Below is an example which will insert one menu item with two sub menu items. Just paste the code in your `functions.php` and log in to your `WordPress` as `admin`. If everything goes right then you can see an extra menu in your administrator bar. To accomplish this, WordPress provided the `admin_bar_menu` hook:

```
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'my_custom_menu', 1000);
function my_custom_menu()
{
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    if(!is_super_admin() || !is_admin_bar_showing()) return;
    // Add Parent Menu
    $argsParent=array(
        'id' => 'myCustomMenu',
        'title' => 'Services',
        'href' => false
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu($argsParent);

    // Add Sub Menus
    $argsSub1=array(
        'parent' => 'myCustomMenu',
        'title' => 'Visit Heera IT',
        'href' => 'http://heera.it',
         'meta' => array('target' => '_blank')
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu($argsSub1);
    $argsSub2=array(
        'parent' => 'myCustomMenu',
        'title' => 'Visit StackOverflow',
        'href' => 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
        'meta' => array('target' => '_blank')
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu($argsSub2);
}
```

For more details, you can [visit Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu).

Comment: It's worth noting also, using `admin_bar_menu` will load your custom content to the left side of the admin bar before the default content.  If you want to load content to the right side you can use `wp_before_admin_bar_render` in place of `admin_bar_menu`.

Comment: This is still working in 2018, but an id is required for the sub menus, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish this using a plugin that allows you to easily customize the content and appearance of the WordPress Admin Bar. Here are a few plugins to consider:

[Plugin #1](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ag-custom-admin/)

[Plugin #2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-adminbar-menus/)

[Plugin #3](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-custom-admin-bar/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array
    (
        "parent" => "bba_booking_bank",
        "id"     => "bba_booking_bank_location",
        "title"  => $bba_location_providers_wizard_setup,
        "href"   => admin_url("admin.php?page=booking_bank"),
    ));
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array
    (
        "parent" => "bba_booking_bank",
        "id"     => "bba_booking_bank_calendar",
        "title"  => $bba_booking_bank_calendar,
        "href"   => admin_url("admin.php?page=bba_booking_calendar"),
    )
);
```